# Is there a tool to read news from different sources?

Tags: web, newsletter

Only subscribed source. Like an RSS, but since many websites don't have RSS now maybe another solution is needed. Looks like Google News can only let the "algorithms" control your flow, and I just want the subscribed source.

Comment: Can you please give a few more details on your needs: as you speak of subscription, should it be an app installed on one of your devices (then please specify the OS), or rather a webapp? Any price considerations? There are some services converting "normal" websites into RSS feeds, though I haven't tried any of them. You can then subscribe to the generated link.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks. I would prefer webapps, though android apps are also viable.  What are those services? They sound like what I needed.

Comment: That is very likely. The Android app uses a web service. Let me see if I can find it… There it is: [RSSHub-Radar](https://github.com/DIYgod/RSSHub-Radar). All in Chinese, so don't get confused. There's a link to the Chrome webstore you might wish to give a look (I don't as it requires me to agree to a list of Google stuff) – so this seems to be the Chrome extension. [RSSHub](https://github.com/DIYgod/RSSHub) has the description in English and the project it all is built upon, so maybe start with that? Seems to be intended for self-hosting, but there may be existing instances somewhere.

Comment: @Izzy This looks like what I needed. Many thanks.

Comment: Cool! Would you mind to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then and accept it, so others in a comparable need can easily identify there's a solution? Ideally include some description to make it clear how it works and how it meets your requirements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I now use https://github.com/DIYgod/RSSHub-Radar to find RSS links from websites, and I also use Inoreader to read the RSS. You can find RSS links in the search function in Inoreader as well.